# Manipulating String-db using R bioconductor package STRINGdb

Tags: r, database, package, interaction, bioconductor

I want to extract a large network from `string-db.org` as the web interface does not support more than 2000 proteins. and I need for about 100.000 to 200.000 proteins.
So I'm using R bioconductor package STRINGdb to explore the database .
As I'm a newbie in R, even with the documentation I have  not idea how to do that nor the functions to use . 
I tried 
PS: I'm Interested in cancer network , (protein-protein interaction dataset)
I had tried :

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("STRINGdb")
library(STRINGdb)
string_db <- STRINGdb$new( version="10", species=9606, score_threshold=0.4, input_directory="" )
##Not sure if it is the right function to use##
string_proteins <- string_db$get_proteins()  ## Returns 20475 obs. 4 variables
```

I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as I read you want the network of 2-4k proteins involved in cancer processes and propably visualize it somehow in R. Hmm it's easy to get information, neighbours and interaction of particular proteins, this is from manual:

```
tp53 = string_db$mp( "tp53" )
atm = string_db$mp( "atm" )
string_db$get_neighbors( c(tp53, atm) )
string_db$get_interactions( c(tp53, atm) )
```

So if you list of proteins it's easy to get info about them.
Due to visualization, function `get_graph` may be useful and it take vector of stringdb proteins so something like `c(tp53, atm)`.

Give some more info what do yowu want to do and we'll figure it out :)

Comment: I have edited the question , I need a network of  f 100.000 to 200.000 proteins (nodes) involved in cancer disease . the network will be used in another application  big data stuff . so If I go you right I should look for  important proteins of cancer and I should do the same procedure you cited above

Comment: Is there another trick to do it faster ? if It is the right way  string_db$get_neighbors( c(tp53, atm,AR,MDM2,TP53BP1) ) then ,string_db$get_interactions( c(tp53, atm, AR,MDM2,TP53BP1) ) but I can see no difference in the interaction number, yet there are interactions between 2 sets

Comment: 100k-200k proteins? You typed: `string_proteins <- string_db$get_proteins()  ## Returns 20475 obs. 4 variables` as I know there are ~20k of genes i human genome. If you provide a list with oncogenes and supressor genes and put them into vector, you can find all interactions in mentioned above functions. You said that there are no difference in the interaction number, check this few genes in string-db there should be the same number

Comment: I should be looking for oncogenes and supressor for cancer (tumor) or  in general ? oncogenes cells

Comment: I think that oncgenes and supressors are most important.

Comment: I did what you told me about , and the interactions I have now are 3916 interaction. for 5827 mapping indentifier , how do I do to get close to the 200k I need ?